# Bypass Input FIle; Uploading Image directly using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, upload

I'd like to automate the uploading of images to a website. The problem is I'm stuck at the input file type. The site seems to use a JQuery uploading method. I'd like to feed the script the image data directly satisfying validation.

Here's the HTML of the input file type used to upload images along with it's structure.

```
<div id="item_img_msg1" abp="568"></div>
<div class="mg_b5 mg_l10" id="item_img_empty1" abp="569">
    <input name="updfile1" class="  " id="item_img_file1" type="file" abp="570">
</div>
<div class="mg_b5 mg_l10" id="item_img_selected1" style="display: none;" abp="571">
    <img id="item_img1" src="/common/images/noimage.gif" abp="572">
    <input id="item_img_del1" style="vertical-align: bottom;" type="button" value="Delete" abp="573">
</div>
<input name="hdnImgDelFlg1" id="imgdelflg1" type="hidden" value="" abp="574">
<span class="font_85 pg_l10" abp="575">(Size：Under 1MB;Format:JPEG,GIF,PNG</span>
<br abp="576">
<span class="pg_l10" abp="577">Wide or Tall images will be chopped</span>
<div class="HelpTxt mg_t5" abp="578">
    Guide:<a href="/common/guide.pdf" target="_blank" abp="579">Image Upload Guide</a>
</div>
```

And here's the related javascript.

```
var ImageUploader = function (idx) {
    var postData = {
        name: "updfile",
        index: idx,
        imgApiType: $("#img_api_type").val(),
        unq: $("#unique_id").val(),
        postCnt: 0
    };
    var deleteData = {
        index: idx,
        imgApiType: $("#img_api_type").val(),
        unq: $("#unique_id").val(),
        postCnt: 0
    };
    var onIamgeUploaded = function (response) {
        var status = $(response).find("otoma_status").text();
        if (status != "0") {
            $("#item_img_msg" + idx).html("<div class='error_with_icon'>Upload Failed</div>");
            return;
        }
        var url = $(response).find("img_url").text();
        $("#item_img" + idx).attr("src", url + "?" + new Date().getTime());
        $("#item_img_empty" + idx).hide();
        $("#item_img_selected" + idx).show();
        $("[name='hdnImgDelFlg" + idx + "']").val("0");
        postData.postCnt++;
    };
    this.manualUpload = function (data) {
        var postDataForManual = $.extend({}, postData, data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: postDataForManual,
            url: "/api/itemimage/upload",
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                var loading_image_tag = $("<img>").attr({
                    "class": "js-loading_image" + idx,
                    src: Module.imgpath + "/lib/fileuploader/loading.gif"
                });
                $("#item_img_empty" + idx).after(loading_image_tag);
                $("#item_img_empty" + idx).hide();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                onIamgeUploaded(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#item_img_msg" + idx).html("<div class='error_with_icon'>Upload Failed!</div>");
                $("#item_img_empty" + idx).show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("img.js-loading_image" + idx).remove();
            }
        });
    };
    var init = function (idx) {
        postData.index = idx;
        try {
            new AjaxUpload("#item_img_file" + idx, {
                action: "/api/itemimage/upload",
                name: "updfile",
                data: postData,
                onSubmit: function (file, extension) {
                    AjaxUtils.loading(true);
                    $("#item_img_msg" + idx).html("");
                },
                onComplete: function (file, response) {
                    AjaxUtils.loading(false);
                    onIamgeUploaded(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {}
        $("#item_img_del" + idx).click(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                dateType: "xml",
                data: deleteData,
                url: "/api/itemimage/delete",
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    deleteData.postCnt = postData.postCnt;
                    $("#item_img_msg" + idx).html("");
                    $("#item_img_empty" + idx).show();
                    $("#item_img_selected" + idx).hide();
                    $("[name='hdnImgDelFlg" + idx + "']").val("1");
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#item_img_msg" + idx).html("<div class='error_with_icon'>Upload Failed!</div>");
                }
            });
        });
    };
    init(idx);
};
var ImageUploaders = [];
var maxImageNumber = $("#max_image_number").val();
for (var i = 1; i <= maxImageNumber; i++) {
    ImageUploaders.push(new ImageUploader(i));
}
var params = Module.Utility.getParameters();
var buying_support_item_id = params.buying_support_item_id;
if (buying_support_item_id) {
    ImageUploaders[0].manualUpload({
        buying_support_item_id: buying_support_item_id
    });
}
```

I can make javascript script calls to the webpage. I just basically need to know which calls to make. Does anyone know how to do this? If so, could you provide sample code.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that you want to feed the script with the image directly? You don't want to use the file upload field? How would you select images?

Comment: I'd select the images from a path on my computer and pass it as postdata. There's a manualUpload function that seems to fit well as the receiver. This of course is a hypothetical approach, I'm open to any suggestion that works.